# Phonegap with HTTPS Login Page

Tags: jquery, html, apache, https, cordova

i'm making a phone gap application that requires login, my app gets the data from a server side service written in PHP, so what i'm planning to do is to setup an apache web server with mod_ssl and use jquery's getJSON to post the username and password and confirm the login

i just need to ask you if i'm missing anything or doing it wrong or if there is a better way to do that

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Greets, `getJSON` sends data as a `GET`, so if you want to send data as `POST` u gotta use a normal ajax post with `$.ajax()` or the simplified way :

```
$.post(url, dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {
  //data contains the JSON object
  //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
}, "json");
```